# Mongodb { $ne: null } VS { $exists }

Tags: mongodb, performance

The `$ne`-like queries are [not very selective](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#read-operations-query-selectivity). Is it better to use $exists when trying to filter on documents where we want the nested document to have any value at all ? Or is it the same in terms of performance ?

Comment: Just FYI, `$exists` is not a drop in for `$ne: null`. `$exists` would return null values too, and will only exclude undefined ones.